# How to interpret and apply results from Inverse Dynamics

Tags: dynamics, inverse-dynamics, bullet

I am applying Recursive Newton Euler Inverse Dynamics to a simple two link model. If I apply the result torques and forces using PhysX or Bullet Physics I get unexpected results. The model spins and deforms instead of rising in the Y direction without rotating and deforming as the input acceleration indicates:

[image: a busy cat]

The Newton Euler Inverse Dynamics (tested with RBDL and Matlab spatial_v2). Returns:

Tau = 0,6,0, -6,0,0, -3,0,0 = (force A, Torque A, Torque B)

When I apply these forces and torques in PhysX and Bullet the bodies deform and rotate. The values that work in Bullet and PhysX are: Fa=0,6,0 Ta=3,0,0 Tb=3,0,0.

When I feed Tau into Forward Dynamics using Composite Body or Articulated Body then the original acceleration is returned.

I am wondering how one applies Tau to a model. Is there a transformation I am missing somewhere? All the joints in the model are aligned with the worldspace axis.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Went to start asking questions about this - what does "deform" mean here, what axis is assumed for the revolute joint, how many joints are there ("joint is revolute" seems to imply one, but then there are two torques given), was the angular acceleration `Qdd` also included in the Bulet/PhysX models, etc. etc., but then realized this question is 5 years old, and the OP was last seen 5 years ago. I don't expect we'll be able to answer/close this question.